# Поймать событие нажатие по ссылке jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть некий Tabs сформированный с помощью виджета в YII2.

```
<li class="active">
    <a href="#tabs-document-repairs-tab1" data-toggle="tab" ariaexpanded="true">ЗИП</a>
</li>
```

Как можно поймать нажатие имея только эти данные?

```
 $('body').on('click', 'ЧТО НУЖНО ВПИСАТЬ СЮДА?', function() {
   //Код
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('body').on('click', "a[href='#tabs-document-repairs-tab1']", function() {
   console.log($(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="active">
    <a href="#tabs-document-repairs-tab1" data-toggle="tab" ariaexpanded="true">ЗИП</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Как-то у вас все сложно сделано. Я сделал полегче.

Comment: И ошибка вылетает.

Comment: @Ver Nick, какая ошибка?

Comment: а вы запустите :)

Comment: @Ver Nick, у меня нет никакой ошибки, можно по подробнее какая именно ошибка?

Comment: не могу сказать, потому что она огромная. Ну раз у вас работает, то значит все ок.

Comment: @Ver Nick, `$(this)` - это объект который относится к элементу, который получил событие. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp

Comment: @VerNick это не ошибка, а содержимое `$(this)`, которое пишется в консоль :-)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko А, понятно.

Comment: Спасибо. Все отлично работает.

Answer (score -1):

Самый простой способ без Jquery, классический Javascript:

```js
function func(){
  alert("Нажата ссылка!");
}
```

```html
<li class="active">
    <a href="#tabs-document-repairs-tab1" data-toggle="tab" ariaexpanded="true" onclick = "func()">ЗИП</a>
</li>
```

Событие `onclick` возникает при щелчке левой кнопкой мыши на элементе, к которому добавлен атрибут `onclick`.

Comment: А минусить то зачем?

Comment: Элемент `li` сформирован с помощью виджета на YII2. Не думаю, что там есть возможность произвольно менять аттрибуты элемента. Если такая возможность есть, укажите это в ответе.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Ну я сделал самым простым способом для новичка.

Comment: Сможет ли ТС  использовать ваш код - вот в чем вопрос!